# Webpack dev server refresh loop madness

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, create-react-app

I've been using my own hand-rolled solution (outside of Webpack) for taking a folder of SVG files, extracting out the contents between `<svg></svg>`, building a JSON file, and then using that to inject into a React component so I can output specific icons with more control over the surrounding attributes.

I came across https://github.com/gilesa/svg-to-json-webpack-plugin which actually does a lot of the same for me, which is awesome! Something odd happened though when attempting to use it with `create-react-app` and what I suspect is the Webpack dev server. Whenever I attempt to import the generated `.json` file, the dev server continually refreshes in the browser.

I go into detail a bit more in the issue I created https://github.com/gilesa/svg-to-json-webpack-plugin/issues/1 but my attempts at debugging exactly what's causing the infinite loop haven't been successful. The Webpack plugin API is pretty great, so I've learned a bit along the way, but no dice thusfar.

Ideally, I'd want Webpack to ignore that specific file if that is what's causing the watcher to kick-off again. Potentially because it's creating a file in the same `src` directory it is looking for changes to? Thanks for any help in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this sounds like a known issuse of [#25](https://github.com/webpack/watchpack/issues/25), try this webpack plugin [webpack-mild-compile](https://github.com/yessky/webpack-mild-compile), it should works.

Comment: why my answer got -1 ?

Comment: Interesting! I think I might have come across that issue as well and will definitiey give it a shot. Appreciate it!